# Can universal instantiation be used more than once?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, formal-proofs

I'm trying to follow a proof in a logic text and it seems like the author used universal instantiation twice to reach the needed result. I was under the impression that you could only use UI one time in a proof.

Comment: Where did you get that impression?

Comment: This may not be particularly interesting to say, but it is indeed that case that, for all real numbers $a$ there exists a real number $c$ such that, for all positive numbers $e$, $e>a+c$.

Comment: I've only ever seen it used once in the proofs I've seen. Intuitively it seems like I should be able to use UI as many times as I want since the statement is true for all objects in the universe. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: If technique X can only be used once in a proof, and I use it to prove A implies B, and use it to prove B implies C, then I wouldn't be able to combine these proofs to show A implies C as that would require two uses, and mathematics would pretty well come to a halt.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents us to use universal instantiation (UI) more than once in a proof.

Consider the formula in the language of *formal arithmetics* :

> $\forall x \exists y (y = S(x))$

where $S(x)$ is the "successor" function.

We can clearly instantiate it with $0$, to get :

> $\exists y (y = S(0))$

which is true when $y$ get the value $1$; and again with :

> $\exists y (y = S(S(0)))$

which is true when $y$ get the value $2$.

---

*Added*

You can see Peter Smith's answer to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197879/restrictions-on-universal-specification-in-first-order-logic).

In order to prove :

> $\forall x \forall yR(x,y) \vdash \forall xR(x,x)$

we have to proceed this way :

*(i)* $\forall x \forall yR(x,y)$ --- assumed

*(ii)* $\forall yR(x,y)$ --- by [Universal Instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)

*(iii)* $R(x,x)$ --- by UI

*(iv)* $\forall x R(x,x)$ --- by [Universal Generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization), $x$ is not free in $\Gamma$, where $\Gamma = \{ \forall x \forall yR(x,y) \}$.